# using jain sip in OSGI bundle

Tags: exception, log4j, osgi, jain-sip

I try to use jain sip API in an OSGi bundle, when i use it in a standard java application, it seems to work when I import the log4j jar. But when i don't import it, i catch an exception when I use the Sipfactory.createStack(Properties p) function. From what i saw in my researches it's because the log4j jar is absent.
Now when i try with an OSGi environment i have the same problem, even when I try to put the lib log4j with the jainsip jars. I just don't know how to make it work, maybe there is a specific manipulation to be able to use log4j.
Moreover i already have another plugin using log4j, i tried to export the log4j lib from this bundle and to import it in my jainsip bundle but it didn't work too.

Comment: What error do you get? Check the Jitsi phone project. They use OSGI with jain sip successfully.

Comment: check out the pax-logging project it's build to reduce this pain on developing other osgi bundle to actually only use it as infrastructure.

Comment: You're very thin on details. What bundle did you exactly use? Was environment are you using?

Answer (score 0):

JAIN-SIP uses log4j-1.2.15.jar. Have you checked if that version of log4j makes any difference?